# How do I speed up the running of terraform deployments using threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, terraform

When creating terraform deployments, I have to wait until the command completes before running the next command.

If I have multiple deployments in parallel - (tf init,apply) commands on different environments running on the same terminal, is there a way to use threading in my python scripts to avoid waiting for deployments to finish before I can run my next deployment?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, you can use threads or multiprocessing in python.

Comment: just open a second terminal

Comment: Your python scripts execute terraform?